# How to concatenate two document lists in a webMethods flow service?

Tags: webmethods, wm-flow

I have sequence of two steps. 
In both of them I get some data from sql database and trying to save them in document list.

only problem is that when the second step of sequence is executing it override my document list instead of adding new elements.

to make it clear I want on my list:
seq1 elements + s2 elements

but i get only 
s2 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `WmPublic` service `pub.list:appendToDocumentList` to construct a new list which is a concatenation of your two lists.

Call `pub.list:appendToDocumentList`, passing your `seq1` list as the `toList` input argument and your `s2` list as the `fromList` input argument, and the service will return a new list called `toList` which is a concatenation of `seq1` and `s2`.